# 960 Grid - Remove the spacing of margin-left and margin-right

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I learn 960 Grid CSS Framework, and I have a HTML code and CSS below:

- HTML code:

```css
@import url( 'css/reset.css' );
@import url( 'css/text.css' );
@import url( 'css/960.css' );

#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
}
#wp_head,
#wp_foot {
 background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
#header,
#footer {
 border:1px dotted #333;
 min-height: 100px;
}
#content {
 border: 1px dotted #333;
 min-height: 500px;
}
#row-1 {
 
}
.row-1-left{
 border: 1px dotted #333;
 background-color: pink;
 min-height: 50px;
}
.row-1-center {
 border: 1px dotted #333;
 background-color: yellow;
 min-height: 50px;
}
.row-1-right{
 border: 1px dotted #333;
 background-color: lime;
 min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Learn 960 grid</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="wp_head">
        <div id="header" class="container_12">Header</div>
       </div>
       <div id="row-1" class="container_12 clearfix">
        <div class="row-1-left grid_4">Left - 4</div>
        <div class="row-1-center grid_4">Center - 4</div>
        <div class="row-1-right grid_4">Right - 4</div>
       </div>
       <div id="wp_foot">
        <div id="footer" class="container_12">Footer</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

And then, show result below (See image attachment):

[image]

**Question:** I want remove margin-left and margin-right. Please help me!

Comment: You can do that but you would have to re-write the whole 960gs system so it would work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cpu5syg1/

Comment: Hello, @ksav, not apply.